# What does the acronym csc in csc.exe stand for?

Tags: csc

A silly question, my google-fu is failing me, I know that the csc.exe is the command line compiler, but I am curious what the letters csc are an acronym of?

Comment: *C Sharp Compiler*, I'd guess?

Comment: "I know that the csc.exe is the command line compiler" - command line compiler *of what*, you think? After all, there are dozens of command line compilers for different languages, there is no such thing as globally *the* command line compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems sort of reasonable to assume that it stands for *C Sharp Compiler*: you can't put `#` in a filename (and it looks odd in an acronym anyway) so `csc` is the closest possible thing.

A quick Google search tells me [this  book](https://books.google.be/books?id=JZmbD7yeNMMC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=csc+%22c+sharp+compiler%22&source=bl&ots=jyr1PkHsw7&sig=ZI2Lgh_uLfvA9vXyVlY3g3kjo2I&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwA2oVChMIspfe8tjMyAIVx-caCh0wBgOJ#v=onepage&q=csc%20%22c%20sharp%20compiler%22&f=false) agrees with me.

Comment: and that would explain why there is a vbc.exe - vb compiler - in the same directory. I'm glad i preempted the question with "A silly question"